# Trying to make a task tracker with notes in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make somehow of a task/project tracker in google sheets.

What I want to happen is
-- there should be a designated cell(ex. cell A5) for each ROW where when I input a string of text
-- it goes to a certain cell, ie cell A2 that has the "Notes" header
-- adds date in front of it
-- cell A5 clears

is this doable?

Comment: It is doable...

Comment: You need to check Spreadsheet API. It has all the methods that can help you achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Enter string in column 5 get string in column 2 with a date preceeding it.

This uses a simple trigger called the onEdit trigger.  It fires whenever a user edits a cell.  In this case if you edit a cell in column 5 it puts the edit string into column 2 of that same row preceeded by the date.

You cannot run this function from the script editor whith getting the error cannot find getRange() of null because it did not receive the event object.

Just paste it into your script editor and go edit Sheet0  if you don't have a sheet0 then change the name of the sheet in the 3 line.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(`${new Date()} ${e.value}`);
  }
}
```

This is what the sheet looks like after add editing a cell in column 5

[image]

- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))
- [onedit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

With reference to your follow up question this is the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue() + `\n${new Date()} ${e.value}`);
    e.range.setValue('');
  }
}
```

And now adding the formatted date:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    let dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue() + `\n${dt} ${e.value}`);
    e.range.setValue('');
  }
}
```

[formatted date codes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I may have phrased my question wrong.

When inputting in COL 5, it should be sent and added to what's already there in COL 2. After the string in COL 5 is added to what's in COL 2, the string in COL 5 should automaticall be deleted. A bit tricky?

Comment: Try that latest version

Comment: You rock man! Last and final piece for me to finish this, how to set the formatting for the date? I only want it to display the Month, Day, Year, Hour, Minute

Comment: What is the exact format that you wish for the date?  Give me a couple of examples please.

Comment: It can either be 
Jan. 01, 2021 - 08:00 AM
or
01/01/2021 - 08:00 AM

Comment: I don't want either or please tell me what you want

Comment: Jan. 01, 2021 - 08:00 AM

Please and thank you!

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome.  Have a good day.